# Mac client is not syncing, any ideas?

Tags: mac, mega

Megasync is just not doing anything at all.  It was working perfectly but stopped a few weeks ago.  I have around 8gb of free space spare, I can access the online client but if I put a new file in my supposedly synced mega folder then it just doesn't do anything at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about installable software and troubleshooting like questions are off-topic on this site. It' might be on-topic in [su] and / or [apple.se].

Comment: Slightly related from [apple.se]: [Why does MEGAsync need my password?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/359965/274411)

Comment: Hi @Rubén, Mega is a cloud service and yes, maybe this is a problem with the client but the main application is a predominantly a web application.  I recommend reopening the question.

Comment: The question is not about using the web application; it's about the Mac client, so I'm sorry, it is off-topic for Web Applications SE. By the way, both answers haven't required to do anything from the web application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, for some reason the blue check-mark next to the sync folder was deselected:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Mac, I have found [THIS](https://donnlee.com/2020/05/28/fix-megasync-stopped-syncing-files/). It might be related to MacOS privacy settings for Megasync.

> Open Mac “System Preferences” app, then “Security & Privacy”.  Click
> “Privacy” at the top. Click “Files and Folders” on the left. On the
> right, find MEGAsync.app and toggle the checkbox to UNCHECKED. If it
> prompts you to quit Megasync, decline. Then toggle the checkbox back
> to CHECKED. When it prompts you to quit Megasync, choose the option to
> quit/close Megasync. Now if you restart Megasync, it should start
> syncing again.  If not, then ensure Megasync Preferences > “Syncs” tab
> has the local folder enabled/checked (see first paragraph, above).

[image]

---

I have personally seen [this problem on Linux](https://askubuntu.com/a/1196776/925128), where the synced directory was on a second drive that was [not mounted](https://github.com/meganz/MEGAsync/issues/223#issuecomment-460234629) at startup, or that was mounted after Megasync started. This can be fixed by delaying the startup of the client as said [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28685/how-can-i-delay-a-specific-program-on-startup/28695#28695).